# OO Lua - How to Stop Accessing Base Class Table?

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua, chess, base-class

Attempting to construct Chess in Lua, Having issues with the Pieces. I have a base "Piece" class, and then a class that inherits the Piece class for each piece. I'm having an issue with overwriting the base class table. One object is created, then when another is created it overwrites the fields in the table.

My Base Class:

```
Piece = {
    killed = false,
    white = false,
    pieceName = nil
}

function Piece:new(white)
    local returnObject = {
        killed = false,
        white = false,
        pieceName = nil
    }
    setmetatable(returnObject, self)
    self.__index = self
    self.white = white
    return returnObject
end

function Piece:isWhite()
    return (self.white == true)
end

function Piece:setWhite(white)
    self.white = white
end

function Piece:isKilled()
    return (self.killed == true)
end

function Piece:setKilled(killed)
    self.killed = killed
end

function Piece:getName()
    return self.pieceName
end

function Piece:setName(name)
    self.pieceName = name
end
```

The Rook Class, for example:

```
require "Piece"

Rook = Piece:new()

function Rook:canMove(board, startSpot, endSpot)
    if endSpot:getPiece():isWhite() == self.isWhite() then
        return false
    end
end
```

Finally I have attempted to call new in these subclasses on the board (Which is a 2D Table of Spots (i.e. tiles) that contain either a piece, or 0:

```
function Board:resetBoard()
    self.boxes[1][1] = Spot:new(1, 1, Rook:new(true))
    self.boxes[1][1]:getPiece():setName("Rook")
    self.boxes[1][5] = Spot:new(1, 5, King:new(true))
    self.boxes[1][5]:getPiece():setName("King")
    ...
end
```

The output I am getting from printing the board is:

```
King    0       0       0       King    0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I've tried a few messy workarounds but can't get anything to work. I feel like the problem lies with setName calling **self**.pieceName, but I'm not sure how else to set up a setter in this way. That's just a guess though, it could be something else.

Any ideas? Don't hesitate to ask for further info.

Comment: Replace `self.white = white` with `returnObject.white = white`

Comment: You assign two different names for `boxes[1][1]`.  A typo?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff 1 - Cheers for that, self.white changed to returnObject.white. 2 - This was indeed a typo, something I'd been playing around with moments before and forgot to change, but doesn't make a difference either way. Ill change it in the question now to avoid confusion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, came down to the "Spot" also needing to be unique. Changed the Spot class, which I didn't mention previously, from:

```
Spot = {
    x = nil,
    y = nil,
    piece = nil
}

Spot.__index = Spot

function Spot:new(x, y, piece)
    local returnObject = {}
    setmetatable(returnObject, self)
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self:setPiece(piece)
    return returnObject
end
```

To:

```
Spot = {
    x = nil,
    y = nil,
    piece = nil
}

Spot.__index = Spot

function Spot:new(x, y, piece)
    local returnObject = {}
    setmetatable(returnObject, self)
    returnObject.x = x
    returnObject.y = y
    returnObject:setPiece(piece)
    return returnObject
end
```